# Calling multiple strings with one intent when using the if/else clause

Tags: android, string, android-intent, webview

Is there a way to call multiple strings with just one intent, like in a webview activity and using the if / else clause like this:

```
public void openGo(View v) {
    TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
    String check = display.getText().toString();
    if (check.contentEquals("1")) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("keyHTML", "file:///android_asset/page1.html");
        startActivity(i);
    } else if (check.contentEquals("10")) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("keyHTML", "file:///android_asset/page2.html");
        startActivity(i);
```

If string 1, and 12 and 16 have the same webview page, how do you link them together? Is this possible like below? NOTICE THE BOLD TEXTS.

```
public void openGo(View v) {
    TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
    String check = display.getText().toString();
    **if (check.contentEquals("1,12,16")) {**
        Intent i = new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("keyHTML", "file:///android_asset/page1.html");
        startActivity(i);
    } else if (check.contentEquals("10")) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("keyHTML", "file:///android_asset/errorpage.html");
        startActivity(i);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use 
`if (check.contentEquals("1") || check.contentEquals("12") || check.contentEquals("16") )` 
I dont think what you use work correctly

Comment: Thank you, I havent used what I pasted, it was just so you would understand what I want, I'll try this tho and thanks a lot! @zohreh